# Make WPF ComboBoxes fill a whole column width

Tags: wpf, combobox, styles

I'm having problems making a `ComboBox` stretch to fill the whole column width in a `GridViewColumn`. It should also resize when the column is resized.

In the following example I have a `StackPanel` with a `ComboBox` inside. This is set to stretch and will in fact stretch to fill the `StackPanel` width.

Then I add a `ListView` with one column, containing a `StackPanel` with a `ComboBox`. Both the `StackPanel` and the `ComboBox` are set to stretch, but they don't. I use background colors to identify the size of the `StackPanel`s, and there is no red unless I set a width or add elements to the `ComboBox` such that it needs more width.

I also tried playing around with the `HorizontalContentAlignment` property without success.

```
<StackPanel Height="59" Margin="45,12,38,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Green">
    <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
</StackPanel>

<ListView x:Name="MyListView" Margin="0,106,0,0">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Num" Width="70">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Background="red" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    <ListViewItem></ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Unless the StackPanel is going to have something in it, you may have better luck with a Border.

Comment: Aware that the StackPanel can be omitted. The example is a simplification of my real problem - where I seem to need a surrounding StackPanel. Therefore I kept it for the question. Please see my comment to @bendeway's answer for details.

Comment: Re your moderator flag; you missed Dec 26th and Mar 6th (unless I'm missing the log wrong)

Comment: Use `DockPanel` instead of `StackPanel`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try setting the `Style` of the `ListViewItem`. I also removed your StackPanel.

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView" Margin="0,106,0,0">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>

    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Num" Width="170">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>

    <ListViewItem></ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks! That works, however - it gives me a new problem. Well, in the simplified example I gave in the question it is all good, but my real list is more complex. 

When adding the styling - without having any StackPanel around - resizing the column is really slow. If I add a surrounding StackPanel with the property Orientation="Horizontal" resizing is smooth. 

This problem occurs when I have typically >1000 elements in my list. Any idea what gives this? Not using your solution, but adding Background="Transparent" gives the same issue. Feels like I've tried everything.. 

Thanks!

Comment: Might add that adding a surrounding StackPanel with horizontal orientation stops the ComboBox from filling the whole column...

Comment: Well, you did answer the question, so I'm closing this one. Thx. 

Please check out my new question about the column resize performance issues: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829242/wpf-column-resize-performance-issues