# ListView Resize Columns Performance Issues (Grouping)

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, xaml, listview

I am experiencing major performance issues with [`ListView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.aspx) whenever I implement grouping. I have found [somewhat similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829242/wpf-column-resize-performance-issues) on StackOverflow, but none seem to help!

---

Here is my current situation (*I have simplified my project so there is less noise*):

I have a [`ContentControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx) with a `ListView` as the child.  The `ListView` is bound to an [`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx), which is initially empty.  As time passes, objects are added to to the collection (in this example, 500 items are added every 10 seconds using a [`DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx)). The size of the `ObservableCollection` will vary, but it's possible the collection could end up being over 25,000 items.

When the `ObservableCollection` has less than 2000 (not exact figure), column resizing looks like this:

[image]

However, as more objects are added to the `ObservableCollection`, there is a noticeable drop in performance (***you need to scroll down for this to occur***).

[image]

This will eventually lead to the `Application` locking up.

I was thinking the problem could be resolved using `Virtualization`, so I tried using the following:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView1"
                  Style="{DynamicResource lvStyle}"
                  VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"
                  VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                  VirtualizingPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="True"
                  ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True">
```

However, nothing seems to work!
Not to mention, `VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"` causes the `ListView` to lock up entirely.

I have also looked into [Paul McClean's excellent Data Virtualization](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization), however, it does not handle grouping.

---

***Question:***  When grouping items in a `ListView`, is there a way to resize the columns without drastically affecting the Application's performance?

Ideally, I would like to reduce memory overhead, so I am all for implementing some sort of asynchronous solution.

---

### CODE:

XAML:

```
<ContentControl x:Class="ListViewDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListViewDemo"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:dat="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Data;assembly=PresentationFramework"
        xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Classic" 
        mc:Ignorable="d" 
        d:DesignHeight="400" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <ContentControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="lvStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
        <Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode" Value="Recycling"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ListView.ItemsSource" Value="{Binding}"/>
        <Setter Property="ListView.View">
            <Setter.Value>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Date">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Desc">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Desc}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="ListView1"
                      Style="{DynamicResource lvStyle}"
                      VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"
                      VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                      VirtualizingPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="True"
                      ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True">
            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                        <DockPanel>
                                            <Border DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                                                <TextBlock x:Name="groupItem"
                                                            Text="{Binding ItemCount, StringFormat={}({0} Results)}"></TextBlock>
                                            </Border>
                                            <ItemsPresenter DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"></ItemsPresenter>
                                        </DockPanel>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</ContentControl>
```

CODE-BEHIND:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace ListViewDemo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : ContentControl
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Event> eventCollection = new ObservableCollection<Event>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
            dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
            dispatcherTimer.Start();

            ListView1.ItemsSource = eventCollection;
            ListView1.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Descending));
            ListView1.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Date", ListSortDirection.Descending));
            ListView1.Items.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Seconds"));
        }

        private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for(var i = 0; i < 500; i++){
                eventCollection.Add(new Event
                {
                    Name = string.Format("Name_{0}", eventCollection.Count),
                    Date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM.dd.yy HH:mm"),
                    Seconds = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("ss")),
                    Desc = "Description"
                });
            }
        }

        public class Event
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Date { get; set; }
            public int Seconds { get; set; }
            public string Desc { get; set; }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: So, I have to ask... Do you really want to show thousands of items in a UI? Would a user really scroll through 25,000 records? Why not only show 25 or 50 at a time, and paginate?

Comment: @BobHorn Ideally, I do not want to show thousands of items at once.  With UI virtualization , the control *should* only create visual containers for the items in the viewport (so anywhere between 25-50).  It seems, once you scroll down in the listview, rather than resizing just the ones in the viewport (the 25-50 items), it resizes all the items. Scrolling is not an issue, just column resizing.  I think this may be an issue with grouping but not positive.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your performance issue is due to not using `IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping`

You mentionned that using `IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping` was locking your application, and this is a known WPF issue (see : http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/780146/freeze-when-using-virtualizingpanel-isvirtualizingwhengrouping for more information on this bug happening when having a custom GroupStyle and `IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping` set to true)

Here is a quick workaroung to solve your issue : You just have to add an expander in the GroupStyle ControlTemplate. You'll then be able to use `IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping` and then have good performances when scrolling/Resizing columns.

Here is the code that works on my machine : (I put everything directly in MainWindow to simplify a bit)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication21.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="lvStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}" >

            <Setter Property="ListView.ItemsSource" Value="{Binding}"/>
            <Setter Property="ListView.View">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Name">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Date">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Desc">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Desc}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="ListView1"
                  Style="{DynamicResource lvStyle}"
                  VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                  VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True">
            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                        <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                            <DockPanel>
                                                <Border DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                                                    <TextBlock x:Name="groupItem"
                                                                Text="{Binding ItemCount, StringFormat={}({0} Results)}"></TextBlock>
                                                </Border>
                                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="groupItemPresenter" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"></ItemsPresenter>
                                            </DockPanel>
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**EDIT:** Here is a ControlTemplate that "hides" the expander. It's the original one from which I removed the unnecessary parts :

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="CustomExpanderControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <DockPanel>
                <ToggleButton x:Name="HeaderSite" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" MinWidth="0" MinHeight="0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                    <ToggleButton.FocusVisualStyle>
                        <Style>
                            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <Border>
                                            <Rectangle Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                                        </Border>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ToggleButton.FocusVisualStyle>
                    <ToggleButton.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                        <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                            <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="0" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Border>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ToggleButton.Style>
                </ToggleButton>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpandSite" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Visible"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Right">
                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Right"/>
                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Left"/>
                <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                        <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                            <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="19"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                                        <TransformGroup>
                                                            <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                                                        </TransformGroup>
                                                    </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                                    <Ellipse x:Name="circle" Fill="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="DarkGray" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M1,1.5L4.5,5 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="False" Stroke="#FF666666" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                </Grid>
                                                <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,4,0,0" Grid.Row="1" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Border>
                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M1,4.5L4.5,1 8,4.5"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="Transparent"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#FF222222"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF526C7B"/>
                                                <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="Transparent"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#FF003366"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="DarkGray"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="Transparent"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#FF666666"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Up">
                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Top"/>
                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Bottom"/>
                <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                        <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                            <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="19"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                                        <TransformGroup>
                                                            <RotateTransform Angle="180"/>
                                                        </TransformGroup>
                                                    </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                                    <Ellipse x:Name="circle" Fill="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="DarkGray" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M1,1.5L4.5,5 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="False" Stroke="#FF666666" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                </Grid>
                                                <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="1" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Border>
                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M1,4.5L4.5,1 8,4.5"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="Transparent"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#FF222222"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF526C7B"/>
                                                <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="Transparent"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#FF003366"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="DarkGray"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="Transparent"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#FF666666"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Left">
                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Left"/>
                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Right"/>
                <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                        <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                            <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="19"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                                        <TransformGroup>
                                                            <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                                                        </TransformGroup>
                                                    </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                                    <Ellipse x:Name="circle" Fill="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="DarkGray" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M1,1.5L4.5,5 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="False" Stroke="#FF666666" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                </Grid>
                                                <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,4,0,0" Grid.Row="1" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Border>
                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M1,4.5L4.5,1 8,4.5"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="Transparent"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#FF222222"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF526C7B"/>
                                                <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="Transparent"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#FF003366"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="DarkGray"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="Transparent"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#FF666666"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

You can use it by setting it in the group style :

```
<Expander IsExpanded="True" Template="{DynamicResource CustomExpanderControlTemplate}">
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is an amazing answer! Also, I never knew about the `IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping` bug!

Comment: Hey @Dom, you're very welcome ! Glad to see my answer helped !

Comment: I did a test where I added 10,000 objects every 15 seconds.  Even after 300,000 results, I had zero problems! This answer is **phenomenal**!! Thank you again, @Sisyphe! I would award you another 1,000 points if I could!

Comment: You bloody life saver! This issue has been plaguing us for weeks. Is Microsoft's supposed hotfix still pending?

Comment: Glad to see this answer is still usefull after almost one year :) I'm not aware aware of any Microsoft fix effectively released regarding this issue but I can be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is the ObservableCollection that is bound to your ListView and the case that you are adding 500 items per Add(). Each Add will raise 3 events. 2 `NotifyPropertyChanged`-Events for property `Count` and property `Item[]` and one the `NotifyCollectionChanged-Event` of the Collection, what counts up to 1500 events that are raised.

I have exchanged the ObservableCollection with my own derived implementation of ObservableCollection that allows me to add a range of items and raise only 3 events once.

```
    public class SmartCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T> {
        public SmartCollection()
            : base() {

        }

        public SmartCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection)
            : base(collection) {

        }

        public SmartCollection(List<T> list)
            : base(list) {

        }

        public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> range) {
            foreach (var item in range) {
                Items.Add(item);
            }

            this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
            this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
            this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        }

        public void Reset(IEnumerable<T> range) {
            if (range == null) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("range", "range is null");
            }

            var rangeToAdd = range.ToList();
            this.Items.Clear();

            AddRange(rangeToAdd);
        }
    }
```

Using my Collection i changed your method to add the elements to the collection

```
private SmartCollection<Event> eventCollection = new SmartCollection<Event>();

private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  List<Event> newEvents = new List<Event>(500);

  for(var i = 0; i < 500; i++){
    newEvents.Add(new Event {
      Name = string.Format("Name_{0}", eventCollection.Count + i),
      Date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM.dd.yy HH:mm"),
      Seconds = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("ss")),
      Desc = "Description"
    });
  }

  eventCollection.AddRange(newEvents);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will definitely look into this!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answer will suit, but I did get that performance back after setting the 
[VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingpanel.scrollunit.aspx) property to "Item".
The problem is, I had a number of visual glitches, which included seeing the Grouping object overlaying the top row when scrolling row-by-row (mouse wheel or key up/down), and the blurring across the rows immediately after scrolling as the renderer kicked in clear up the text.

```
VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Item"
```

Edit:
Also change the VirtualizationMode back to Standard, VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard", and the visual glitches almost dissapear. (Having been testing with 50,000 rows).

Comment: Thank you for your effort! Unfortunately, I am still having issues :(

Comment: @Dom What issues are you still having?