# How can I make a WPF combo box have the width of its widest element in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I know how to do it in code, but can this be done in XAML ?

Window1.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Name="ComboBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ComboBoxItem>ComboBoxItem1</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>ComboBoxItem2</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Window1.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            double width = 0;
            foreach (ComboBoxItem item in ComboBox1.Items)
            {
                item.Measure(new Size(
                    double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
                if (item.DesiredSize.Width > width)
                    width = item.DesiredSize.Width;
            }
            ComboBox1.Measure(new Size(
                double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
            ComboBox1.Width = ComboBox1.DesiredSize.Width + width;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out another post on the similar lines at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826985/make-wpf-comboboxes-fill-a-whole-column-width Please mark your question as "answered" if this answers your question.

Comment: I have tried this approach in code as well but found that the measurement can vary between Vista and XP. On Vista, DesiredSize usually includes the drop down arrow size but on XP, often the width does not include the drop-down arrow.  Now, my results may be because I'm attempting to do the measurement before the parent window is visible.  Adding an UpdateLayout() before the Measure can help but can cause other side-effects in the app.

I'd be interested in seeing the solution you come up with if you are willing to share.

Comment: How did you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This can't be in XAML without either:

- Creating a hidden control (Alan Hunford's answer)
- Changing the ControlTemplate drastically.  Even in this case, a hidden version of an ItemsPresenter may need to be created.

The reason for this is that the default ComboBox ControlTemplates that I've come across (Aero, Luna, etc.) all nest the ItemsPresenter in a Popup.  This means that the layout of these items is deferred until they are actually made visible.

An easy way to test this is to modify the default ControlTemplate to bind the MinWidth of the outermost container (it's a Grid for both Aero and Luna) to the ActualWidth of PART_Popup.  You'll be able to have the ComboBox automatically synchronize it's width when you click the drop button, but not before.

So unless you can force a Measure operation in the layout system (which you **can** do by adding a second control), I don't think it can be done.

As always, I'm open to an short, elegant solution -- but in this case a code-behind or dual-control/ControlTemplate hacks are the only solutions I have seen.

Answer (score 62):

You can't do it directly in Xaml but you can use this Attached Behavior. (The Width will be visible in the Designer)

```
<ComboBox behaviors:ComboBoxWidthFromItemsBehavior.ComboBoxWidthFromItems="True">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Short"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Medium Long"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Min"/>
</ComboBox>
```

The Attached Behavior ComboBoxWidthFromItemsProperty

```
public static class ComboBoxWidthFromItemsBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ComboBoxWidthFromItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached
        (
            "ComboBoxWidthFromItems",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(ComboBoxWidthFromItemsBehavior),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnComboBoxWidthFromItemsPropertyChanged)
        );
    public static bool GetComboBoxWidthFromItems(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(ComboBoxWidthFromItemsProperty);
    }
    public static void SetComboBoxWidthFromItems(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ComboBoxWidthFromItemsProperty, value);
    }
    private static void OnComboBoxWidthFromItemsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject dpo,
                                                                DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox = dpo as ComboBox;
        if (comboBox != null)
        {
            if ((bool)e.NewValue == true)
            {
                comboBox.Loaded += OnComboBoxLoaded;
            }
            else
            {
                comboBox.Loaded -= OnComboBoxLoaded;
            }
        }
    }
    private static void OnComboBoxLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        Action action = () => { comboBox.SetWidthFromItems(); };
        comboBox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action, DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
    }
}
```

What it does is that it calls an extension method for ComboBox called SetWidthFromItems which (invisibly) expands and collapses itself and then calculates the Width based on the generated ComboBoxItems. (IExpandCollapseProvider requires a reference to UIAutomationProvider.dll)

Then extension method SetWidthFromItems

```
public static class ComboBoxExtensionMethods
{
    public static void SetWidthFromItems(this ComboBox comboBox)
    {
        double comboBoxWidth = 19;// comboBox.DesiredSize.Width;

        // Create the peer and provider to expand the comboBox in code behind. 
        ComboBoxAutomationPeer peer = new ComboBoxAutomationPeer(comboBox);
        IExpandCollapseProvider provider = (IExpandCollapseProvider)peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.ExpandCollapse);
        EventHandler eventHandler = null;
        eventHandler = new EventHandler(delegate
        {
            if (comboBox.IsDropDownOpen &&
                comboBox.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
            {
                double width = 0;
                foreach (var item in comboBox.Items)
                {
                    ComboBoxItem comboBoxItem = comboBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as ComboBoxItem;
                    comboBoxItem.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
                    if (comboBoxItem.DesiredSize.Width > width)
                    {
                        width = comboBoxItem.DesiredSize.Width;
                    }
                }
                comboBox.Width = comboBoxWidth + width;
                // Remove the event handler. 
                comboBox.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged -= eventHandler;
                comboBox.DropDownOpened -= eventHandler;
                provider.Collapse();
            }
        });
        comboBox.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += eventHandler;
        comboBox.DropDownOpened += eventHandler;
        // Expand the comboBox to generate all its ComboBoxItem's. 
        provider.Expand();
    }
}
```

This extension method also provides to ability to call

```
comboBox.SetWidthFromItems();
```

in code behind (e.g in the ComboBox.Loaded event)

Comment: +1, great solution! I was trying to do something along the same lines, but eventually I used your implementation (with a few modifications)

Comment: Amazing thanks. This should be marked as the accepted answer. Looks like attached properties are always the way to everything :)

Comment: Best solution as far as I am concerned. I tried multiple tricks from all around the Internet, and your solution is the best and easiest one I found. +1.

Comment: Note that if you have multiple comboboxes in the same window (*it happened for me with a window creating the comboboxes and their content with code-behind*), the popups can become visible for a second. I guess this is because multiple "open popup" messages are posted before any "close popup" is called. The solution for that is to make the whole method `SetWidthFromItems` asynchronous my using an action/delegate and a BeginInvoke with an Idle priority (as done in the Loaded event). This way, no measure will be done while the messge pump is not empty, and thus, no message interleaving will occur

Comment: Is the magic number: `double comboBoxWidth = 19;` in your code related to `SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidth`?

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2015, this solution works at runtime but not at design time. (by not working I mean, doesn't size to contents--whether hard-coded XAML items or data-bound items), and causes some slight glitches in the designer itself

Comment: This does not adapt to scaling text on win10 + 4K display. it goes to foreach (var item in comboBox.Items) -loop but ContainerFromItem returns null

Comment: If you do not open the combobox and then close the hoster of the control the event handlers don't unsubscribe and it results in memory leaks.

Comment: The `provider.Expand()` method throws an `ElementNotEnabledException` when the control itself or any parent control is disabled as FlyingFoX pointed below Mike Post's answer.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, just one add. I'm using sharedSizeGroup and with this solution the sharedSizeGroup is not working as combobox will always be refering to the item size.
I added a check wether desired width is already greater than calculated width. If so with comboBox width override is skipped.
`double calculatedWidth = comboBoxWidth + width;
if (calculatedWidth > comboBox.DesiredSize.Width)
{
    comboBox.Width = comboBoxWidth + width;
}`

Answer (score 14):

Based on the other answers above, here's my version:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding EnumValues}" Height="0" Margin="15,0"/>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding EnumValues}" />
</Grid>
```

HorizontalAlignment="Left" stops the controls using the full width of the containing control.
Height="0" hides the items control.
Margin="15,0" allows for additional chrome around combo-box items (not chrome agnostic I'm afraid).

Comment: This is by far the simplest answer. It's ridiculous to have to do it but it's an order of magnitude less complex and ridiculous than the other workarounds. Why there isn't a SizeToOptions property, or this isn't simply the default behaviour of the control, is beyond me! WPF is completely mental sometimes. Nice one, Gaspode!

Answer (score 11):

Yeah, this one is a bit nasty.

What I've done in the past is to add into the ControlTemplate a hidden listbox (with its itemscontainerpanel set to a grid) showing every item at the same time but with their visibility set to hidden.

I'd be pleased to hear of any better ideas that don't rely on horrible code-behind or your view having to understand that it needs to use a different control to provide the width to support the visuals (yuck!).

Comment: Will this approach size the combo wide enough so that the widest item is fully visible when it's the selected item? This is where I've seen problems.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up with a "good enough" solution to this problem being to make the combo box never shrink below the largest size it held, similar to the old WinForms AutoSizeMode=GrowOnly.

The way I did this was with a custom value converter:

```
public class GrowConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public double Minimum
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var dvalue = (double)value;
        if (dvalue > Minimum)
            Minimum = dvalue;
        else if (dvalue < Minimum)
            dvalue = Minimum;
        return dvalue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Then I configure the combo box in XAML like so:

```
 <Whatever>
        <Whatever.Resources>
            <my:GrowConverter x:Key="grow" />
        </Whatever.Resources>
        ...
        <ComboBox MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Converter={StaticResource grow}}" />
    </Whatever>
```

Note that with this you need a separate instance of the GrowConverter for each combo box, unless of course you want a set of them to size together, similar to the Grid's SharedSizeScope feature.

Comment: Nice, but only “stable” after having selected the longest entry.

Comment: Correct.  I had done something about this in WinForms, where I would use the text APIs to measure all the strings in the combo box, and set the min width to account for that.  Doing the same is considerably more difficult in WPF, especially when your items are not strings and/or are coming from a binding.

Answer (score 3):

A follow up to Maleak's answer: I liked that implementation so much, I wrote an actual Behavior for it.  Obviously you'll need the Blend SDK so you can reference System.Windows.Interactivity.

XAML:

```
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfStuff}">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <local:ComboBoxWidthBehavior />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </ComboBox>
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Automation.Peers;
using System.Windows.Automation.Provider;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

namespace MyLibrary
{
    public class ComboBoxWidthBehavior : Behavior<ComboBox>
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            AssociatedObject.Loaded += OnLoaded;
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            base.OnDetaching();
            AssociatedObject.Loaded -= OnLoaded;
        }

        private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var desiredWidth = AssociatedObject.DesiredSize.Width;

            // Create the peer and provider to expand the comboBox in code behind. 
            var peer = new ComboBoxAutomationPeer(AssociatedObject);
            var provider = peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.ExpandCollapse) as IExpandCollapseProvider;
            if (provider == null)
                return;

            EventHandler[] handler = {null};    // array usage prevents access to modified closure
            handler[0] = new EventHandler(delegate
            {
                if (!AssociatedObject.IsDropDownOpen || AssociatedObject.ItemContainerGenerator.Status != GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
                    return;

                double largestWidth = 0;
                foreach (var item in AssociatedObject.Items)
                {
                    var comboBoxItem = AssociatedObject.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as ComboBoxItem;
                    if (comboBoxItem == null)
                        continue;

                    comboBoxItem.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
                    if (comboBoxItem.DesiredSize.Width > largestWidth)
                        largestWidth = comboBoxItem.DesiredSize.Width;
                }

                AssociatedObject.Width = desiredWidth + largestWidth;

                // Remove the event handler.
                AssociatedObject.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged -= handler[0];
                AssociatedObject.DropDownOpened -= handler[0];
                provider.Collapse();
            });

            AssociatedObject.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += handler[0];
            AssociatedObject.DropDownOpened += handler[0];

            // Expand the comboBox to generate all its ComboBoxItem's. 
            provider.Expand();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work, when the ComboBox is not enabled. `provider.Expand()` throws an `ElementNotEnabledException`. When the ComboBox is not enabled, due to a parent being disabled, then it is not even possible to temporarily enable the ComboBox until the measuring has finished.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution to the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4414372/3096657) is to [Measure the Popup](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2010/08/31/wpf-auto-size-combobox/) itself rather than measuring all the items. Giving slightly simpler `SetWidthFromItems()` implementation:

```
private static void SetWidthFromItems(this ComboBox comboBox)
{
    if (comboBox.Template.FindName("PART_Popup", comboBox) is Popup popup 
        && popup.Child is FrameworkElement popupContent)
    {
        popupContent.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
        // suggested in comments, original answer has a static value 19.0
        var emptySize = SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidth + comboBox.Padding.Left + comboBox.Padding.Right;
        comboBox.Width = emptySize + popupContent.DesiredSize.Width;
    }
}
```

works on disabled `ComboBox`es as well.

Comment: This solution doesn't have to briefly show the Combobox, in order to measure its contents' size, which is a good improvement over the original top answer.

Comment: It works but combobox occupies more space then content needs to. Comparing to original answer where emptySize is static 19, here emptySize computed value 27.

Comment: I believe it's `SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidth` that adds extra width. Funny thing is that it's added regardless whether vertical scrollbar is displayed or not.

Answer (score 2):

In my case a much simpler way seemed to do the trick, 
I just used an extra stackPanel to wrap the combobox.

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ExecutionTimesModeList}" Width="Auto"
        SelectedValuePath="Item" DisplayMemberPath="FriendlyName"
        SelectedValue="{Binding Model.SelectedExecutionTimesMode}" />    
</StackPanel>
```

(worked in visual studio 2008)

Answer (score 1):

Put an listbox containing the same content behind the dropbox. Then enforce correct height with some binding like this:

```
<Grid>
       <ListBox x:Name="listBox" Height="{Binding ElementName=dropBox, Path=DesiredSize.Height}" /> 
        <ComboBox x:Name="dropBox" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alun Harford's approach, in practice :

```
<Grid>

  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <!-- hidden listbox that has all the items in one grid -->
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items, ElementName=uiComboBox, Mode=OneWay}" Height="10" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Hidden">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel><ItemsPanelTemplate><Grid/></ItemsPanelTemplate></ListBox.ItemsPanel>
  </ListBox>

  <ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectedIndex="0" x:Name="uiComboBox">
    <ComboBoxItem>foo</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>bar</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>fiuafiouhoiruhslkfhalsjfhalhflasdkf</ComboBoxItem>
  </ComboBox>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted it to only resize to the max element while the dropdown is open, and otherwise fit to the selected value. Here's the code for that:

Based in part on Frederik's answer (which didn't actually work for me)

```
public static class ComboBoxAutoWidthBehavior {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ComboBoxAutoWidthProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "ComboBoxAutoWidth",
                typeof(bool),
                typeof(ComboBoxAutoWidthBehavior),
                new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnComboBoxAutoWidthPropertyChanged)
            );

    public static bool GetComboBoxAutoWidth(DependencyObject obj) {
        return (bool) obj.GetValue(ComboBoxAutoWidthProperty);
    }

    public static void SetComboBoxAutoWidth(DependencyObject obj, bool value) {
        obj.SetValue(ComboBoxAutoWidthProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnComboBoxAutoWidthPropertyChanged(DependencyObject dpo, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        if(dpo is ComboBox comboBox) {
            if((bool) e.NewValue) {
                comboBox.Loaded += OnComboBoxLoaded;
                comboBox.DropDownOpened += OnComboBoxOpened;
                comboBox.DropDownClosed += OnComboBoxClosed;
            } else {
                comboBox.Loaded -= OnComboBoxLoaded;
                comboBox.DropDownOpened -= OnComboBoxOpened;
                comboBox.DropDownClosed -= OnComboBoxClosed;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void OnComboBoxLoaded(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) {
        ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox) sender;
        comboBox.SetMaxWidthFromItems();
    }

    private static void OnComboBoxOpened(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) {
        ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox) sender;
        comboBox.Width = comboBox.MaxWidth;
    }

    private static void OnComboBoxClosed(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) => ((ComboBox) sender).Width = double.NaN;
}

public static class ComboBoxExtensionMethods {
    public static void SetMaxWidthFromItems(this ComboBox combo) {
        double idealWidth = combo.MinWidth;
        string longestItem = combo.Items.Cast<object>().Select(x => x.ToString()).Max(x => (x?.Length, x)).x;
        if(longestItem != null && longestItem.Length >= 0) {
            string tmpTxt = combo.Text;
            combo.Text = longestItem;
            Thickness tmpMarg = combo.Margin;
            combo.Margin = new Thickness(0);
            combo.UpdateLayout();

            combo.Width = double.NaN;
            combo.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));

            idealWidth = Math.Max(idealWidth, combo.DesiredSize.Width);

            combo.Text = tmpTxt;
            combo.Margin = tmpMarg;
        }

        combo.MaxWidth = idealWidth;
    }
}
```

And you enable it like this:

```
<ComboBox behaviours:ComboBoxAutoWidthBehavior.ComboBoxAutoWidth="True" />
```

You could also just set Width directly instead of MaxWidth, and then remove the DropDownOpened and Closed parts if you want it to behave like the other anwsers.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the answer myself, when I came across the `UpdateLayout()` method that every `UIElement` has.

It's very simple now, thankfully!

Just call `ComboBox1.Updatelayout();` after you set or modify the `ItemSource`.

Answer (score 0):

This keeps the width to the widest element but only after opening the combo box once.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxItems}" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="sharedSizeGroup"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```