# How to set width of DataGridTemplateColumn by content?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am a new in WPF and my question is there a way to set width of column by the most width item in this column?

When I run my app this column looks like this

[image]

Word `<EXISTING CALIBRATIO` is shrink. This word should be shown entirely like `<EXISTING CALIBRATION>`

Like when drop down list is open

[image]

My code for this column is

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{x:Static res:Resources.geo_calib_folder}">
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <ComboBox x:Name="Cb_geometry_calibration"
                                                  ToolTip="{x:Static res:Resources.tooltip_chosen_geometry_calibration_folder}"
                                                  PreviewMouseWheel="Cb_PreviewMouseWheel"
                                                      SelectionChanged="Cb_geometry_calibration_SelectionChanged"
                                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GeoCalibrationFolders}"
                                                      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedGeoCalibrationFolder}"
>
                                                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <TextBlock 
                                                        Text="{Binding Path=UIRepresentation}" />
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

                                                <ComboBox.Style>
                                                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsGeoCalibFolderBold}" 
                                                                         Value="True">
                                                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                                                            </DataTrigger>
                                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                                    </Style>
                                                </ComboBox.Style>

                                                <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                                    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                                                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
                                                    </Style>
                                                </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                            </ComboBox>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

So, question is there a way to resize this column dynamically according to content?

P.S. I understand that I can hardcode this value like `width = 300`, but I would like to find a way to make it dynamically.

Comment: Did you try by setting `Width=Auto`? Something like `<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" `

Comment: @trix it doesn't help... It set width by header... as far as I understand

Comment: Is there any style applied ?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko: Did you try to reproduce this in a new blank app?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [duplicate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034505/how-can-i-make-a-wpf-combo-box-have-the-width-of-its-widest-element-in-xaml), you can't do it directly in XAML.  It requires some code behind or attached behaviors because the combobox resolves its width prior to the retrieval of its collected items.