# Trying to implement a class using System.Windows DependencyProperty (windowsbase.dll) in a C# Avalonia UI project and failing

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, avaloniaui

I am using the latest version of Avalonia UI and I need to size the drop-down contents of a ComboBox to it's widest member. So I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034505/how-can-i-make-a-wpf-combo-box-have-the-width-of-its-widest-element-in-xaml) solution and I'm trying to implement it. Here's the code for reference:

```
public static class ComboBoxWidthFromItemsBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ComboBoxWidthFromItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached
        (
            "ComboBoxWidthFromItems",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(ComboBoxWidthFromItemsBehavior),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnComboBoxWidthFromItemsPropertyChanged)
        );
    public static bool GetComboBoxWidthFromItems(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(ComboBoxWidthFromItemsProperty);
    }
    public static void SetComboBoxWidthFromItems(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ComboBoxWidthFromItemsProperty, value);
    }
    private static void OnComboBoxWidthFromItemsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject dpo,
                                                                DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox = dpo as ComboBox;
        if (comboBox != null)
        {
            if ((bool)e.NewValue == true)
            {
                comboBox.Loaded += OnComboBoxLoaded;
            }
            else
            {
                comboBox.Loaded -= OnComboBoxLoaded;
            }
        }
    }
    private static void OnComboBoxLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        Action action = () => { comboBox.SetWidthFromItems(); };
        comboBox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action, DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately when I create the class, VS2022 is telling me that `The type or namespace name 'DependencyProperty' could not be found.`

[image]

After looking it up, DependencyProperty is in the `System.Windows` namespace and the assembly is `WindowsBase.dll`.

So I added `using System.Windows;` to the top of my class, but that didn't resolve the problem. I read a couple other solutions on here and they instruct to add `windowsbase.dll` as an assembly reference.

Thing is, according to my solution, it's already referenced (I think):

[image]

The path is `C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\7.0.4\ref\net7.0\WindowsBase.dll`.

It shows up in my solution's Dependencies under `Frameworks > Microsoft.NETCore.App`

So how can I get VS2022 to stop complaining that the namespace `DependencyProperty` and `DependencyObject` can't be found?

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`DependencyProperty` is for WPF and does not work in Avalonia. You are looking for `StyledProperty` in AvaloniaUI.

```cs
public static readonly StyledProperty<Brush> BackgroundProperty =
    AvaloniaProperty.Register<Border, Brush>(nameof(Background));

public Brush Background
{
    get { return GetValue(BackgroundProperty); }
    set { SetValue(BackgroundProperty, value); }
}
```

You can read more in the documentation [here](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/authoring-controls/defining-properties).